How to get rid of a blank space where the featured image used to be?
I want my featured image, or post thumbnail, for the post to be displayed on the "posts" or "home" page (they are the same on my site), but not on the actual post. This is easy with my theme because you can simply uncheck a box to have the image not appear on the post. However, it leaves a giant gaping blank space at the top of the post where the image would be. This would confuse visitors, so I need to get rid of that blank space! Any help with this is greatly appreciated!
The theme I'm using is Book Blogger.

Chances are that your theme has a minimum height set on a container where that featured image loads - but, as it's a third party theme and your question doesn't have any code for us to help you with, you'll be hard pressed to get an answer here. Have you asked the theme developer?  Their support channel is the best place to ask this question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
